# How to calculate this long recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

Here is a code doing recursion which crashes for larger values:

```
int rec(int m,int n)      
{
    if(m==0)
        return n+1;
    if(m>0 && n==0)
        return rec(m-1,1);
    if(m>0 && n>0)
        return rec(m-1,rec(m,n-1));
}
```

If I call the function `rec(m,n)`:

- with `m=1` and `n=2`, the result I get is `4`
- with `m=2` and `n=2`, it is `7`,
- with `m=3` and `n=2`, it is `29`

But *it crashes* for `m=4` and `m=2`. Is there an alternate way to calculate it?

Comment: Is this ackermann's function? :D

Comment: So what's your question? Do you want to know *why* it crashes, do you want to make it work for (4, 2)? Something else?

Comment: yes,it is Ackermann's function.

Comment: How to evaluate this long recursion. :)

Comment: declare m and n as double, and use some kind of map to store already calculated values (for caching purposes), but it won't increase range much. It just fills stack too fast. If you can increase stack size that would be even better.

Comment: i want to calculate value of (m=4,n=2)

Comment: could you find a better wording for `but it is terminates for m=4 and m=2` and ask an actual question? And give the *exact* error you're getting? (N.B.: in three close votes your question will be on hold)

Comment: `m(4,2)` equals `2^65536-3`. The recursion depth is about the same. You just need to buy a computer with *way* more bits of memory than there are electrons in this Universe, and wait *way* more time than will pass until heat death of said Universe.

Comment: Ackerman 4,2 has 19,729 decimal digits. You need some pretty special code to calculate numbers that big. You won't get it from this question.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is **hangs**. Not "terminates", but "hangs". Or maybe **crashes**. Could you reword the question, please.

Comment: @dsp: What happens if m is less than 0?  It doesn't recurse.

Comment: @ Thomas :It is Ackermann function which is only  defined for natural numbers (non-negative integers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ackermann's function can be stated non-recursively as

> Ack( m, n )  =  (2 op<sub>m</sub> (n + 3)) - 3

where op<sub>m</sub> is the m'th arithmetic operation in the order addition, multiplication, exponentiation, tower function, ...

In other words it explodes in value pretty darn instantaneously, with no way to represent those numbers as C++ integers.

For an explanation see my homepage from the 1990's :),
(http://web.archive.org/web/20120315031240/http://members.fortunecity.com/alf_steinbach/content/programming/narrow_topics/ackermann/ackermann.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
rec(4,2)
-> rec(3, rec(4, 1))
          ->rec(3, rec(4, 0)
                   ->rec(3, 1)
                   ->rec(2, rec(3, 0))
                            ->rec(2, 1)
                            ->rec(1, rec(2, 0))              -->rec(1, 2) //return 4
                                     ->rec(1, 0) //return 2     -->rec(0, rec(1, 1)) //return 4
                                     ->rec(0, 1) //return 2               -->rec(0, rec(1, 0)) //return 3
                                                                                    -->return 2
```

this boils down to:

```
rec(4,2)
-> rec(3, rec(4, 1))
          ->rec(3, rec(4, 0)
                   ->rec(3, 1)
                   ->rec(2, rec(3, 0))
                            ->rec(2, 1)
                            ->rec(1, 4)
```

This can be solved further but the space is insufficient and will take a lot of time.
I am predicting that your application either crashes due to stackoverflow or due to reaching the limit of allowable recursions.
But I cannot say for sure...
@Cheers and hth. - Alf explains it mathematically in much more subtle manner ;)

Comment: Surely you aren't trying to write out the callgraph for A(4, 2)? You'll probably hit the (very generous) length limit for answers, if you don't go mad first.

Comment: Initially I thought I could come down to the end of the recursion, but now I see where this is going. So will stop for now... :)

Comment: +1 for the attempt at intelligent communication. ;-)